# this keyword used in callback function inside constructor behavior

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I'm using the RxJS and exploring its functions while learning TypeScript. I came across this Observable constructor:

```
constructor(subscribe?: (this: Observable<T>, subscriber: Subscriber<T>) => TeardownLogic) {
    if (subscribe) {
        this._subscribe = subscribe;
    }
}
```

To create a new Observable I should pass an optional `subscribe` callback to the Observable constructor.

I'm not sure I understand how the `this` keyword is used in this context. It seems that the callback function accepts two parameters `this` and `subscriber`. I tried to make sense out of it and compare it to an example listed in the RxJS documentation:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

const observable = new Observable((subscriber) => {
  subscriber.next(1);
  subscriber.next(2);
  subscriber.next(3);
  setTimeout(() => {
    subscriber.next(4);
    subscriber.complete();
  }, 1000);
});
```

I'm aware that the `this` used in the constructor refers to the current Observable instance being created and that the constructor will eventually call the `subscribe` function and pass it the instance being created. But that still seems to be strange to me because I expect to be working with the first parameter `this` if I only pass one argument to the `subscribe` callback like when working with high order functions such as `forEach`:

`forEach(callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => void, thisArg?: any): void;`

The `index` and `array` parameters are usually not needed so I can call `forEach` and only pass the first parameter `value` but that's not the case in the Observable constructor.

Can someone enlighten me on how this works?

Answer (score 2):

The first parameter `this` is actually fictional. It's the way typescript has to annotate that the function will have the `this` keyword bound to an object of the specific type. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#declaring-this-in-a-function

An example:

```
// This typescript code //
interface Rational {
  numerator: number,
  denominator: number
}

function add(this: Rational, num: number) {
  return this.numerator / this.denominator + num;
}

const myRational: Rational = {
  numerator: 1,
  denominator: 2
};
add.call(myRational, 0.4);

// Transpiles to //
function add(num) {
  return this.numerator / this.denominator + num;
}

const myRational = {
  numerator: 1,
  denominator: 2
};
add.call(myRational, 0.4);
```

Reminder `.call()` is a method that all functions have, where it lets you call it but specifying a specific "this" value, which is passed as the first parameter. Similar to `Function.bind()` or `Function.apply()`

This example I added is just to show how the `this: Rational` parameter is just removed from the transpilation, but you wouldn't usually use it like this. As mentioned in the docs, this is useful for consumers of a library on callback-style arguments, such the one on Observable.

Comment: "The first parameter this is actually fictional" um, err, nitpick: it *isn't*: every Javascript function called in the context of a given object, e.g. `foo.bar()`, `bar.call(foo)`, etc has an *implicit* argument of `this` handled by the JS runtime. Perhaps a better way to say it than "fictional" would be that it makes something that is usually *implicit* an explicit type annotation.

Comment: @JaredSmith You could imagine that `this` is passed as an argument by the JS runtime, but it's not part of any standard. You won't find `this` in the `arguments` object either. Actually, for the same rule, you could argue that `arguments` is also implicitly passed as an argument by the JS runtime, but it's not. My "fictional" word just meant that on JS it really doesn't exist, you can't even put `this` keyword explicitly in the argument list. It's something defined only by typescript, and it gets removed when transpiled to JS. Just as if it was a type definition of a `const` declaration.

Comment: "not part of any standard" ok, to be even more pedantic every method invocation occurs in the context of an [Environmental Record](https://262.ecma-international.org/14.0/#sec-environment-records) which includes an abstract operation of [GetThisBinding](https://262.ecma-international.org/14.0/#sec-resolvethisbinding) that resolves the usage of the `this` keyword in the method invocation, and the Typescript-ism the OP is referencing is explicitly typing the value that abstract operation of a conformant ECMAScript implementation resolves to. I can make the case for your use of "fictional" ...

Comment: ... after all as you point out (I think) it's not part of the formal parameter list, I just think there are other words that fit the situation better, i.e. *implicit*. At the end of the day it's your answer, you do you.